# Is there any way I can combine the similar actions in redux-toolkit?

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js, redux-toolkit

I have similar actions, If I select cart, cart should set to true and all other to false. Is there a way I can just write it in one action rather than separate actions for all of them?

I need something like "if payload == cart,true" then set cart to true and others to false.

```
const initialState = {
  cart: false,
  addNewAddress: false,
  addNewCard: false,
  changePassword: false,
};

export const overlaysSlice = createSlice({
  name: "overlays",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    cart: (state, { payload }) => {
      for (var key in state) {
        state[key] = false;
      }
      state.cart = payload;
    },
    addNewAddress: (state, { payload }) => {
      for (var key in state) {
        state[key] = false;
      }
      state.addNewAddress = payload;
    },
    addNewCard: (state, { payload }) => {
      for (var key in state) {
        state[key] = false;
      }
      state.addNewCard = payload;
    },
    changePassword: (state, { payload }) => {
      for (var key in state) {
        state[key] = false;
      }
      state.changePassword = payload;
    },
    
  },
});

export const {
  cart,
  addNewAddress,
  addNewCard,
  changePassword,
} = overlaysSlice.actions;

export default overlaysSlice.reducer;
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your question, `payload` is a string that could have values such as 'cart', 'addNewAddress', 'addNewCard', and 'changePassword'. If this is the case, you could use one action whose slice reducer function looks like this:

```js
<action_name>: (state, { payload }) => {
  return {
    ...initialState,
    [ payload ]: true
  };
}
```